# generic List receiving null value

Tags: java, spring, generics

In my spring appication, I have the following method in amy generic service class (the try/catch blocks were omitted to keep it simple):

```
@Transactional
public Map<String, List<?>> getListaValores() {
    System.out.println(":"+this.getName());
    Map<String, List<?>> map = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
    Entidade ent = null;
    List<String> lista = null;

    ent = (Entidade) this.entityClass.newInstance();
    lista = ent.getListaArgumentos();

    for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("::"+lista.get(i));
        Class<?> clazz;
        Dao<?> obj;

        String class_name = "com.spring.loja.model."+lista.get(i).toLowerCase()+".persistence."+lista.get(i)+"Home";
        clazz = Class.forName(class_name);
        obj = (Dao<?>) clazz.newInstance();

        if(clazz != null) {
            System.out.println("clazz not null");
            List<?> temp = obj.findAll();
            map.put(lista.get(i), temp);
        } else {
            System.out.println("clazz is null");
            map.put(lista.get(i), null);
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

All it's ok until the execution reaches this line:

```
List<?> temp = obj.findAll();
```

where `temp` is receiving `null`, despite the fact the method findAll in the Dao class being executed, with the correct entity class.

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

Comment: And how does the `findAll()` method in `Dao` class looks like?

Comment: You tagged you question with `spring` but it looks like you a instanciating a new `Dao` at each iteration outside of any application context. How do these `Dao` objects find their configuration ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta this way: https://github.com/klebermo/loja.cms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/loja/config/generic/persistence/Dao.java

Comment: @RohitJain this is my Dao class: https://github.com/klebermo/loja.cms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/loja/config/generic/persistence/Dao.java

Comment: Don't silently swallow exceptions, _ever_, **ever**.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know, as I said, I remove the try/catch blocks to keep the code simple, but they exist.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my question isn't the same as the other you suggest it's the same (I don't even use `@Autowired` here)

Comment: Don't be so quick. If you debug, you will probably find that your `Dao`'s  `sessionFactory` is `null` and therefore throwing a `NullPointerException` which is caught in `findAll` and returns `null`.

Comment: Did that clear it up?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, thanks. that was the problem.